# Differences between travel insurance issued by a credit card as opposed to an insurance company?

Tags: canada, insurance, payment-cards

Does anybody have any experience making a claim with a credit card company while using their travel/medical insurance as oppose to an insurance company package & what are the differences between the two. Particularly ones available to Canadians. What are the pros and cons of each type?  Which one is the easiest to claim?

Edit: I actually want to know if it's possible to just travel with credit card insurance as the only coverage and has anybody done so and maybe has an example.  Zero insurance coverage from any other sources besides the credit card.

Can anyone help me edit? It's definitely travel-related.  I'm just a zombie right now.

Comment: As it stands I fail to see the link with travel. I know you mean travel insurance, but it might be worth mentioning that somewhere in the post. :)

Comment: travel insurance offered by credit cards are typically underwritten by insurance companies, and often you will go through them when you make claims

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on which credit card you have and which travel/medical insurance policy you have. Typically, the credit card insurance is considered secondary, meaning any other policy will have to pay out first. Additionally, you may want to check and see if your travel/medical insurance policy is secondary or primary. Oftentimes they are secondary to any other health insurance you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Credit card insurance usually just covers emergency evacuation, returning of remains (if yo die), and the like. There are specialized travel insurance companies that will sell you insurance for your stay. These policies often cover medical expenses locally, as well as providing the same or additional coverage that your credit card might provide.

For example, if you were traveling in Russia and got sick and had to visit a hospital, it is unlikely that your credit card policy would cover the payments. If however, you died while traveling in Russia, the credit card company might cover bringing your remains back to your home country.

Some countries require travel insurance (beyond what a credit card provides) for long-term stays.

Comment: What is considered a long-term stay?

Comment: @verve It varies per-country and per-visa type.